# Max value of $9\lambda^2 -2 \mu^2$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry

Suppose vector $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$, $\mathbf{c}$ such that:
\begin{align}
    \lvert \mathbf{a} \rvert &= \mu \lvert \mathbf{b} \rvert \\
    \lvert \mathbf{c} \rvert &= \lambda \lvert \mathbf{b} \rvert \\
    \lvert \mathbf{c} \rvert ^2 &= \lvert \mathbf{a} \rvert \cdot 
                                   \lvert \mathbf{b} \rvert - 
                                   \lvert \mathbf{a}-\mathbf{c} \rvert \cdot
                                   \lvert \mathbf{b}-\mathbf{c} \rvert
\end{align}
If $\lvert \mathbf{a} \rvert$, $\lvert \mathbf{b} \rvert$, 
$\lvert \mathbf{a} - \mathbf{b} \rvert$ are edges of a triangle which area is 1.

If $\lvert \mathbf{a}-\mathbf{b}\rvert$ take the minimum value, then what the maximum value of $9 \lambda^ 2 - 2 \mu ^2$ are ?

Comment: It is not evident that to a minimal value of $|a-b|$ corresponds a **maximal value** of $9 \lambda^ 2 - 2 \mu ^2$. Could you say a little more what motivates this question, moreover with these coefficients (why not $\pi \lambda^ 2 + e \mu ^2 - \sqrt{3} \lambda \mu$ :)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. **$|a-b|$ take minimal value** is a restriction, dose not mean that when $|a-b|$ is minimum then $9\lambda ^2 - 2 \mu ^2$ get maximal value. I think vector a b c are suppose to have some relations as above expressions stated. And I don't actually know why this question take coefficients like that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My opinion is that your problem has too difficult-to-understand parameters and constraints that the fact that $|a-b|$ is minimum looks impossible to take into account. Where does this problem and its constraints comes from ? There is a big risk that under its present form, you will attract no answer.